# Graph DriveItem returned WebUrl format different for .txt and .docx

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I am currently using a delta query to retrieve drive items for my drive e.g.

```cs
var delta = await client
                .Sites["siteId"]
                .Drives["driveId"]
                .Root.Delta()
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
```

This is returning as expected, my question is to do with the WebUrl property that is returned. For .txt files it will return the absolute URL e.g.
`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/doclibrary/file.txt` but for a .docx it will return something like the following: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=GUID&file=file.docx&action=default&mobileredirect=true`

Is there a way to force SharePoint or Graph to return the WebUrl in an absolute format so .txt and .docx paths are the same?

Or another Graph property that will allow this to be worked out (e.g. REST has a server relative URL property)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For drive items, this is by default that the WebUrl format is different between office files and non-office files.

As a workground, you could use the graph api to get listItems in the library like this:

```
var items = await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Lists["{list-id}"].Items
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

The weburl property for all files are the same in the response.

Comment: Problem is I cannot do a delta call on a list, only on a drive. Also (from my tests) I cannot expand the ListItem facet of a DriveItem when doing a delta call...